# how to set differently popup screen in react?

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Dialog screen for insert data. so I wrote codes to show dialog screen. but when the dialog show, I can't click previous screen. I want to copy from prev screen and paste to dialog screen. please let me know the way. here is my code.

```
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={this.handleClickOpen}>
                    add customer
                </Button>
                <Dialog open={this.state.open} onClose={this.handleClickClose}>
                    <DialogTitle>add customer</DialogTitle>

                </Dialog>
```

Comment: set Data into the React state and then you can easily access from the state inside modal.

Comment: actually he is taking about when you open a dialog, the background screen becomes inaccessible and you cant copy and thing unless the dialog is closed.

Comment: is there any solution? I have to use background screen.